# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. But I use POST method

Tags: python, laravel, post, request

I have a problem, when I go to reload the Laravel page to which I am sending a JSON file I get this error however both in the route and in the request I use the post method.
Can someone help me?

Laravel code for the route:

```
Route::post('dictionary', [DictionaryController::class, 'store'])->name('dictionary');
```

Laravel code for controller:

```
class DictionaryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('backend.auth.user.dictionary');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $request;
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And python code where I send post request:

```
mac_dict = {}
ip = 'http://192.168.1.6:14000/api/dictionary'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    def readFile():
        with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/device.txt", "r") as file:
            for i in file:
                line, *lines = i.split()
                if line in mac_dict:
                    mac_dict[line] += lines
                else:
                    mac_dict[line] = lines
        print(mac_dict)
        print("\n")
    
        json_obj = json.dumps(mac_dict, indent=4)
        with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/mac_addr.json", "w") as json_file:
            json_file.write(json_obj)
    
        my_json_data = json.load(open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/mac_addr.json"))
        print(my_json_data)
        req = requests.post(ip, data=my_json_data)
        print(req.text)
        print(req.json())
```

Comment: Try to POST with postman - if error still acquired - problem in laravel, if not - problem in python.

Comment: You have asked this many times, and I have answered it. Since it's a cross between programming languages, I believe, this question needs a more detailed explanation of what you'd expect.